# How to setup custom principal class

Tags: java, jboss6.x, jaas

I am trying to use a custom principal class in a JBoss 6.1 Final. From [the JBoss documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbosssecurity/docs/6.0/security_guide/html/Login_Modules.html) it looks like that I must add the line

```
    <principalClass="es.caib.gesma.browseldap.LdapPrincipal"/>
```

into the login-config.xml file, but it is not clear exactly where. I have tried at a few location in my application policy definition but it always causes an exception to be thrown.

The places where I have tried (one at a time) are:

```
<application-policy name="GesManPolicy">
                                          <----- Here
  <authentication>
                                          <----- Here
    <login-module code="es.caib.gesma.browseldap.BrowseLdapLoginModule" flag="required">
                                          <----- And here
    <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</module-option> 
    ...
```

The exception that I get each time is

```
10:17:05,359 WARN  [XMLLoginConfigImpl] End loadConfig, failed to load config: vfs:/C:/desarrollo/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/conf/login-config.xml:
org.jboss.security.auth.login.ParseException: Encountered " <ANY> "<?xml "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting one of:
<EOF>
<IDENTIFIER> ...
at org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.generateParseException(SunConfigParser.java:415) [:3.0.0.CR2]
at org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.jj_consume_token(SunConfigParser.java:352) [:3.0.0.CR2]
at org.jboss.security.auth.login.SunConfigParser.config(SunConfigParser.java:99) 
....
```

Any idea of where/how I should setup the custom principal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, JBoss documentation is wrong. Using the `module-option` of a module (*does that mean that the principal is not passed to the module by the container, but created by the module?*) it works.

```
<module-option name="principalClass">es.caib.gesma.browseldap.LdapPrincipal</module-option>
```

In case you are checking this, the next trouble you will be getting to get the JBoss container with this object (instead of a SimplePrincipal copy). To do that, your module must add your principal object to the `RolesSets`, like this:

```
protected Group[] getRoleSets() throws LoginException {
  SimpleGroup callerPrincipal = new SimpleGroup("CallerPrincipal");
  callerPrincipal.addMember(this.getIdentity()); <--- YOUR PRINCIPAL OBJECT
  Group[] roleSets = { userRoles , callerPrincipal };
  return roleSets;
}
```